# Cannot read property of undefined 'refreshToken'

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

Trying to write a Redux middleware to refresh a token - I'm getting 'Cannot read property refreshToken of undefined on .refreshToken({refreshToken: refreshToken}).

How is this actually possible to error?

```
 function checkExpiredToken({ getState, dispatch }) {
        return next => action => {
            let user = getState().auth.user;

            if (user && user.refreshToken && moment(user.expiryDate).isBefore(moment())) {
                let refreshToken = user.refreshToken;

                if (refreshToken) {
                    auth0.auth
                        .refreshToken({ refreshToken: refreshToken })
                        .then(credentials => {
                            // Set the Bearer Authorization header on every axios request
                            axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `${credentials.tokenType} ${
                                credentials.idToken
                            }`;

                            dispatch({ type: REFRESHED_TOKEN, payload: credentials });
                            next(action);
                        })
                        .catch(console.error);
                }
            } else {
                next(action);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: What creates this: "auth0.auth" ?

Comment: import auth0 from "react-native-auth0";

Comment: Do you have this at the top of your code? (and please show all the code necessary): import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0';

const auth0 = new Auth0({ domain: '{YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN}', clientId: '{YOUR_CLIENT_ID}' });